# Is it possible to store some guild id in a set in discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, set, discord, discord.js

I want to store some guilds id into my bot. I used `Set()` but it is not useful because when my bot goes offline then all id's from my set are removed so I would need to add them again and again. Is there any solution for that?

I tried this:

```
const collection = new Set();

if (message.content.startsWith(!verify)) {
    collection.add(message.guild.id)
    return message.channel.send("Server Verified");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use [quickdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, I agree with Francois S. This is how you would do it with Quick.DB (`npm i quick.db`)

```
const db = require("quick.db");

if (message.content.startsWith(!verify)) {
db.set(`${message.guild.id}-verify`, true);
return message.channel.send("Server Verified");
}
```

Then in another command you could check if that is equal to true:

```
const db = require("quick.db");

let verifyTrue = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-verify`)
if(verifyTrue == true) {
blah blah blah
}
```